# width='100%' in react native for images whose native width is smaller than max screen dimensions

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am on react native v.42 using width='100%' with images created for an iphone 7 @2x (750px width). This works properly for the iphone 7, but if I look at the images on a 7plus, they get clipped at the top and bottom. In order to prevent this, I have to save out the images for a 7plus (818px @2x).

Does anyone know how to use width='100%' and have the image scale beyond its maximum native dimensions proportionally? Changing resize mode does not work. I also don't want to use any plugins if I can help it.

I know that I can explicitly define the height and width based on the window Dimensions:

```
    import { Dimensions } from 'react-native'

    const { height, width } = Dimensions.get('window')

    export {
      height as deviceHeight,
      width as deviceWidth,

}
```

and use a ratio calculation for the height, but I am looking for a way to not have to declare dimensions for the height (essentially a `height: auto`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Theres a few things you can try.

Try telling the image to cover the screen

```
resizeMode: 'cover'
```

Because this is all flexbox layout you can use align-self to tell the child to stretch

```
alignSelf: 'stretch'
```

If neither of these work for you.. Another alternative that I've done before is to remove the static size so that it will grow naturally (by specifying null for the width and height)

```
width: null,
height: null
```

[Facebook docs on support](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/image.html#background-image-via-nesting)